# Using "this" with multiple selects

Tags: javascript, jquery

Want to fully uderstand how "this" in Jquery works.

Some HTML that generates 3 select dropdowns, error message and button

```
<select class="kwas">
 <option value="-1">-- wybierz --</option>
 <option value="yes">tak</option> 
 <option value="no">nie</option>
</select>

<div style="display: none;" class="error">Can't be done</div>

<select class="kwas">
 <option value="-1">-- wybierz --</option>
 <option value="yes">tak</option> 
 <option value="no">nie</option>
</select>

<div style="display: none;" class="error">Can't be done</div>

<select class="kwas">
 <option value="-1">-- wybierz --</option>
 <option value="yes">tak</option> 
 <option value="no">nie</option>
</select>

<div style="display: none;" class="error">Can't be done</div>

<button class="button">Click Me!</button>
```

jQuery function:

```
$(".kwas").change(function(){
        if ( $(this).val() == 'no' ) {
                $('.error').hide();
                $('.button').show();
            }
            else {
                $('.error').show();
                $('.button').hide();
            }
        });
```

What I want to achive, is not to reapeat myslef and write one function that will display
the error message on the particular select that has a value of "yes" but not on the others.
If any of the selects has a value of "yes" hidde the button.

I know how to write it in ugly way but how to make it elegant ?

http://jsfiddle.net/szymondzumak/Z8f6n/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help guys! You were close, but the thing was that I needed to have .button diasabled even if one answer was " yes ". In your solutions, when I set answers to " yes, yes, no " the last "no" made the button active. What works for me is:

```
$(".kwas").change(function(){
 if ($(this).val() == 'no' ) {
      $(this).next('.error').hide();    
 } else {
      $(this).next('.error').show();
 }

 if($('#a1').val() === 'yes' ||
    $('#a2').val() === 'yes' ||
    $('#a3').val() === 'yes' ){
    $('.button').hide();
 } else {
     $('.button').show();
 }
});
```

Does the job but I don't think it's elegant. All additional #id and nasty if.
Any feedback appreciated

http://jsfiddle.net/szymondzumak/sdV93/

Answer (score 4):

Try using the [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) method, it allow you to find the next element in the DOM, in your case a element with a `.error` class, for sample:

```
$(".kwas").change(function(){
     if ($(this).val() == 'no' ) {
          $(this).next('.error').hide();
          $('.button').show();
     } else {
          $(this).next('.error').show();
          $('.button').hide();
     }
});
```

Comment: Cool thanks! Just a note that it works for <select> but not for the button. Probably next() for the button isn't required.

Comment: Sorry @Szymon, my code was wrong, not it's right :) I correct the code.

Comment: No worries and one more thing. It seems when I will make mixed answers like yes, no, no it still allows me to click the button.

The thing is, even when I have only one yes and rest no. Button must be hidden : )

Answer (score 1):

you can try this.

```
$(".kwas").change(function(){
  if ( $(this).val() == 'no' ) {
    $(this).next('.error').hide()
    $('.button').show();
  }else {
    $(this).next('.error').show();
    $('.button').hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: Close, it seems that when I have yes, no, no I can still click the button. The logic is even if I have only one yes. Hide the button.